# parquet-dotnet writes parquet as V1 or V2

Tags: pyspark, parquet

How to determine if the parquet file generated by C# parquet-dotnet library is parquet V1 or V2.

There is nothing mentioned in the documentation. If anyone knows about it, please share the details.
Thanks